# Does Perl have a module similar to docopt?

Tags: perl, perl-module

Is there any Perl module that have similar functionality to Docopt or is there a port being developed for it?

Docopt is a module that creates an interface for command line calls from parsing the usage and options messages.

You create the standard help message like

```
    Naval Fate.

    Usage:
      naval_fate ship new ...
      naval_fate ship  move   [--speed=]
      naval_fate ship shoot  
      naval_fate mine (set|remove)   [--moored|--drifting]
      naval_fate -h | --help
      naval_fate --version

    Options:
      -h --help     Show this screen.
      --version     Show version.
      --speed=  Speed in knots [default: 10].
      --moored      Moored (anchored) mine.
      --drifting    Drifting mine.
```

and then the options handler is created for you instead of writing them again with Getopt::Long and also handle the commands parsing (I use App::Cmd for that).

Seems that it started in Python and now is implemented in many other languages.

http://docopt.org/

https://github.com/docopt/docopt

Comment: [Docopt](https://metacpan.org/module/Docopt)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perl has [Docopt](https://metacpan.org/module/Docopt) as pointed out in the comments by @marderh. In addition, there are other modules that provide similar functionality such as [Getopt::Auto](https://metacpan.org/module/Getopt::Auto), [Getopt::Euclid](https://metacpan.org/module/Getopt::Euclid), [Getopt::AsDocumented](https://metacpan.org/module/Getopt::AsDocumented) …

Comment: Thanks I have just seen that since two month ago there is a Perl implementation https://github.com/docopt/docopt.org/issues/5. I did not googled for it because http://docopt.org/ has not updated the last part of its page where the implementations are listed, and Perl is missing there, so I wrongly assume there was none.