# perl add options in pod documentation from hash in GetOptions

Tags: perl

This is naive question for which I struggled to find an elegant solution. I write perl scripts that as they mature, grow in the number of options passed to GetOptions. The important options for the script, I add on top as POD documentation, but I rely on giving meaningful names to the other options, and I don't bother to document them explicitly.

I would like to pass the hash in GetOptions somehow to the content printed by `perldoc`, so that the non-documented options is listed there. Any option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ralize that your point of view is code first and document later the things that become stable. That is fair when you need to write twice docs and code. But nowadays that is not true. My recomendation for prototyping is write the manpage and use a module that create the code of the options for you.

My favorite in perl and python is [docopt](https://github.com/docopt/docopt) (and has implementations for many other languages). Here you can find the [Perl Docopt](https://metacpan.org/pod/Docopt)

I asked about [perl implementatios for docopt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18336946/does-perl-have-a-module-similar-to-docopt) long time ago in stackoverflow and I was pointed to the [docopt](https://metacpan.org/pod/Docopt) module and other options like [Getopt::Euclid](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Getopt::Euclid), [Getopt::Auto](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Getopt::Auto) and [Getopt::AsDocumented](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Getopt::AsDocumented)

Related with your concern about not incrementing cpan dependencies,
in python Docopt is selfcontained but I think it is not true for perl implementation which depends on 
boolean,
Class::Accessor::Lite,
List::MoreUtils,
List::Util,
parent,
Pod::Usage
and
Scalar::Util; and the dependencies of the dependencies....

If the perl Docopt implementation is not as small and selfcontained as the original Python then  probably is time to give it wider usage and start to fill feature/implementation requests because, IMHO, the doctopt way of doing things is ONE of the many ways of doing the things right.

Finally here you have a talk about the why of docopt. It is about python but command line interfaces logic and UX are the same for all the languages: [PyCon UK 2012: Create *beautiful* command-line interfaces with Python](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pXhcPJK5cMc)

Answer (score 5):

perldoc parses pod. You'd have to write a script to modify your .pl's pod based on values obtained by running your .pl... Yeah, that doesn't sound like a good idea.

You might be interested in [Getopt::Euclid](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Getopt%3a%3aEuclid), [Docopt](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Docopt), [Getopt::Auto](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Getopt%3a%3aAuto) or [Getopt::AsDocumented](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?GEtopt%3a%3aAsDocumented). These take the opposite approach: You define the options in the documentation, and they parse the documentation to determine how to process the command line.

Comment: Getopt::Euclid sounds like my cup of tea, I'll give it a try. Silly question but, nothing else that is already in the core modules and does not require a module dependency?

Comment: If you want to find out what modules are included in core, use [`corelist`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?corelist) (comes with [Module::CoreList](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Module::CoreList))